# How to check if scrollbar thumb is visible? (part of scrollbar that gets dragged around)

Tags: javascript, html, css

For my application, the scrollbar is always present as a placeholder -- whether or not it is actually functional (or if a thumb exists). As a result, checking if a scrollbar is visible does not help. To get around this, am trying to detect if the scrollbar is active by checking the thumb.

With ::-webkit-scrollbar, would assume it is possible to check the thumb's height. However, it is not fully supported across browsers. Is there another way to check for the presence of a scrollbar thumb?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if **scrollHeight** is bigger than **clientHeight** , then we know the scrollbar would be shown since there would be overflow the container element holding.

Comment: For this application, the scrollbar is always visible -- even if there is nothing to scroll and the scrollbar thumb is not present. As such, checking for the presence of a scrollbar alone is not useful. Trying to find a solution that can work around that if possible.